# Is WebRTC GetUserMedia() broken in Firefox 28?

Tags: html, webrtc, getusermedia

On [this HTML5Rocks WebRTC Demo page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)  If i open any of the demos in firefox <strike>or chrome</strike> i get this error:

`getUserMedia() not supported in your browser`

When i check: http://caniuse.com/stream
It should be working from Chrome 21+ and FF 17+

Interestingly enough, the demo works fine in Opera 12.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the demo and how to fix it?

[EDIT]
Apparently i was not on the latest Chrome (i was still on 33).  It was waiting for me to restart to switch to chrome 34.  After restarting it worked fine.  But it is still not working in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most definitely not. I have tested my WebRTC app and it works just fine. Did you test it as `mozGetUserMedia`? I am guessing that the site is not utilizing a shim and is only using `webkit` for its demo implementations.
You may want to utilize [adapter.js](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js?r=3905) as a shim for your application.

EDIT: yes, it only looks for the non-prefixed and `webkit` prefixed implementations.
Below is code taken from the page itself for the first capture button.

```
var button = document.querySelector('#capture-button');
var localMediaStream = null;

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia('video', function(stream) {
      video.src = stream;
      video.controls = true;
      localMediaStream = stream;
    }, errorCallback);
  } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.controls = true;
      localMediaStream = stream;
    }, errorCallback);
  } else {
    errorCallback({target: video});
  }
}, false);
```